# problem in reading text file with iphone sdk

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

i m trying to read a text file from my app bundle the contents of file are:

1234567890

but when i display the string after reading its like this:

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf320
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0  1234567890
\
\
\
\
\
\
\
\
}

how can i get the exact string and not the garbage ? my code is this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pankaj"    ofType:@"rtf"];  
  if (filePath) {  
  NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  

 if (myText) {  
  NSLog(@"%@",myText); 
 }  
 }
```

good answers will ve appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a rich-text formatted resource (rtf) as plain text. The string you get is the plain text representation of that rtf resource.

Why don't you add the file as a plain text file?

Comment: how to make text file in mac i thought it only has .rtf extension

Comment: No, .rtf extension is used for rich-text formatted files. Plain text files have usually .txt extension (though plenty other extensions contain plain text as well, for example .h/.cpp). I don't have access to a Mac, but I am sure that TextEdit and XCode both should be capable of saving a file as a plain text file.